# Display DIV instead of Section / Article in IE

Tags: html, css

I basically want to create a webpage which supports HTML5's semantic elements however for browsers, which doesn't note the HTML5 elements, what can I do?

For example I'd like to use `<section></section>` which is noted by modern browsers, but what could I do to show a DIV instead of a SECTION if someone visits my site in an older browser?

I have tried to use the following code, which would only be useful for Internet Explorer, but hat about other browsers?

```
<section class="main">
  <!--[if IE]>
  <div  class="main-ie"> Only displayed only in IE .</div>
  <![endif]-->
</section>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I great way to get around this issue is to include the JavaScript polyfill library [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). It makes the HTML5 elements work in older versions of IE. That way you can start using HTML5 semantic tags now rather than waiting until old IE dies ;)

Comment: What's if the user doesn't have JS enabled? Then I guess all my code would be broken into a lot of pieces. :(

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about having JS disabled today, basically everyone has it enabled on both their desktops and phones. The entire internet would be heavily broken if JavaScript was turned off.

Comment: Hmm, this makes sense. So I shouldn't be worried? Really? JS is my only fear because I thought that it is disabled on a lot of places.

Comment: It was 10 years ago, not anymore.

Comment: Oh, okay! Thank you! Btw, yeah if I look at Google Analytics it also uses JS and it basically tracks every visitor. :) Thank you now I'm happy, I thought that a lot of people doesn't have JS enabled :)

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 Shiv enables use of HTML5 sectioning elements in legacy Internet Explorer and provides basic HTML5 styling for Internet Explorer 6-9, Safari 4.x (and iPhone 3.x), and Firefox 3.x.

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: What's if the user doesn't have JS enabled? Then I guess all my code would be broken into a lot of pieces. :(

Comment: use like this
<section>
  <div class="main">Text</div>
</section>
write css to div tag, not section tag
In IE, section tag is consider as container, so the div tag works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can inclide this tiny script for IE:

```
(function(){if(!/*@cc_on!@*/0)return;var e = "abbr,article,aside,audio,bb,canvas,datagrid,datalist,details,dialog,eventsource,figure,footer,header,hgroup,mark,menu,meter,nav,output,progress,section,time,video".split(','),i=e.length;while(i--){document.createElement(e[i])}})()
```

IE understands new and custom elements if you use `document.createElement`.

Ref: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/make-html5-elements-work-in-old-ie/

Comment: Is there any other way to get around this? Because it is javascript... What should I expect? About how many people have javascript disabled browsers? Much? Because if a lot of them has, than the code would be broken, if they are using an old browser.

Comment: There is not other way to force IE understand these elements. Just use old good `divs` if users without javascript are important for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your head tag IE browser support HTML5 tag,

```
 <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.toyotapriusprojects.com/wp-content/themes/html5/lib/js/innershiv.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
```

Comment: What's if the user doesn't have JS enabled? Then I guess all my code would be broken into a lot of pieces. :(

Comment: Normal user doesn't use web developer tool. And all morden browser supports JS.